# How do I set a default PHP version/interpreter in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

Every time I open a new project or folder, I have to set the PHP version in the IDE along with the interpreter. I want to set 7.4 as the default. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You have global config and project config. You can set the global on the startup dialog or disable the "visible only for this project checkbox" on the appropriate dialog. You should ask those questions in the PHPStorm Forum, not on a programming site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just use `File | New Projects Settings | Settings for New Projects...` and set the settings there.

This will be applied for every new project that will be created in the future on that computer.

Obviously, this has to be global PHP interpreter (that is available on the same OS where you run PhpStorm) and not project-specific one (e.g. Docker based interpreter is project-specific).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional step related to LazyOne's answer above. Once you access 'New Project Settings' > 'Settings for New Project'... You need to Select "Language and Frameworks'  > PHP and then in that configuration area you will point the interpreter to the Language version you want. Finally Ok will set that as the default

[PHP Storm Default Interpreter Selection Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Wj57.png)